# Does the contrasting "avoir beau" logically connect the first and second half of this sentence?

Tags: usage

This is a professionally translated sentence:

> Ces frères jumeaux ont **beau** avoir un don pour paraître calmes en toute circonstance, j’ai **rarement** vu Oliver aussi anxieux. –  {Oliver is one of the "*ces frères jumeaux*"}

I don't see how the second half of the sentence can be considered in any way to be in contrast with the first half. The use of "*rarement*" seems illogical and incongruous, clashing with the contrasting "*avoir beau*". I would have phrased  the sentence as:

> (D'habitude) ces frères jumeaux ont **beau** avoir un don pour paraître calmes en toute circonstance, j’ai vu Oliver extrêmement anxieux (aujourd'hui).

Or, without using "*avoir beau*":

> Ces frères jumeaux ont (d'habitude) un don pour paraître calmes en toute circonstance, (**et**/**alors**) j’ai rarement vu Oliver aussi anxieux (qu'aujourd'hui).

---

(In response to Stéphane's comment below) Or I'd say  something like:

> Oliver a **beau** avoir le trac à tout bout de champ – que ce soit avant de faire un discours ou une présentation, il s'est montré carrément anxieux aujourd'hui.
>
> Oliver a **beau** avoir le trac à tout bout de champ – que ce soit avant de faire un discours ou une présentation, je l’ai **rarement** vu aussi anxieux.

It's just that, when I want to say "*someone is particularly edgy today*" in the second half of the sentence, I find it more logical to phrase the first part with "*avoir beau*" as something like "***avoir le trac** à tout bout de champ*", as opposed to "*paraître **calme** en toute circonstance*".

Comment: Interesting. This sentence felt weird, but it was hard for me to undestand why. Your confusion made me understand what's going on. There's a conflict between the idiomatic meaning of the phrasing “j'ai rarement vu X aussi Z” which is “today X is particularly Z…” relating the present and its literal value which relates the past.

Answer (score 1):

Quelques impressions sur le thème de la cohérence :

On dit « indirectement » que même si Olivier, un des deux frères, a le don de paraître calme en toutes circonstances, on l'a rarement vu aussi anxieux (précédemment) *qu'aujourd'hui, qu'en ce moment* : j'interprète ça comme une **ellipse d'une comparaison sous-entendue**... Il ne s'agit pas d'anxiété dans l'absolu. Le verbe est au passé composé, et à moins d'indications contraires (*qu'il ne l'était hier*) on se situe dans le présent. De plus, il n'est pas étonnant qu'on l'ait *rarement* vu être aussi anxieux s'il semble calme dans toutes les circonstances...

Mais à mon avis, l'étrangeté de la première phrase tient entre autres du fait qu'on n'a pas d'**unité des sujets** (*les deux frères, Olivier*) et il s'ensuit une impression de déconnexion entre les deux parties de la phrase au lieu d'avoir un pronom dans la deuxième partie (comme dans la deuxième série d'exemples avec *je l'ai...*). On doit faire une déduction plutôt que d'avoir un ensemble grammaticalement cohérent.

Mais surtout, j'ai l'impression qu'une **locution verbale** ([*avoir beau*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_beau)) à valeur [concessive](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/concession) peut avoir le même sens mais pas nécessairement le **même impact en termes de fonction qu'une locution conjonctive, conjonction** (*quoique* etc.) en tête de phrase. Certaines propositions (subordonnées concessive) ou certains compléments (de concession) semblent mieux introduits ou plus clairs avec des conjonctions. C'est mon hypothèse ici. Incidemment, *avoir beau avoir un don* me semble lourd.

D'autre part les propositions avec le *trac* sont formulées sur le modèle de la concessive, mais ne contiennent **pas d'opposition** il semble ; il est toujours anxieux, et là c'est encore plus qu'à l'habitude, un plus haut degré ; par opposition dans la première série à ne jamais le paraître qui devrait faire échec à l'être en ce moment ou davantage maintenant que précédemment (anxieux). Dans ce deuxième contexte (*trac*), pourquoi employer la locution verbale à valeur concessive sans possibilité que ce qu'elle contienne n'entrave l'action (*il viendra, bien qu'il soit malade*) ? Ça m'apparaît superflu mais ça ne me tracasse pas plus que ça.

---

Mes exemples de formulation :

> J'ai rarement vu (auparavant) Olivier aussi anxieux (qu'il ne l'est aujourd'hui) bien qu'il ait le don de paraître calme en toute circonstance.
>
> Olivier a (<s>beau avoir</s>) toujours le trac, mais là c'était
> encore pire que d'habitude, il était carrément anxieux.

---

En résumé *avoir beau* suivi de l'infinitif est une locution verbale à valeur concessive signifiant *bien que/malgré que/quoique* etc. J'estime que la première phrase est bien formulée quoique un peu lourde, mais que la concessive est moins clairement exprimée qu'avec son équivalent en locution conjonctive/conjonction en tête de phrase. Il n'y a pas lieu de changer le temps du verbe ni de retirer *rarement* qui fait partie d'une comparaison. Donc oui. Dans la phrase avec le *trac* le recours à la concessive m'apparaît essentiellement inutile et je préfère d'autres formulations. Donc non.

Comment: J'aimerais bien voir une question sur la concessive sans idée d'opposition... Peut-être que d'autres réponses sauront m'éclaire là-dessus.